# trying to make a system so you can buy items with coins in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried to make a system so when you you had enough coins you could buy an item and when you clicked the button if you had enough coins it would give the item to you

I started coding and when I thought I was done I tried it and it did not work here is my code:

```
local currency = 3

local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local CoolSword = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("CoolSword")

function BuySword(plr)
    if currency > 2 then
        currency = currency - 3
        plr:WaitForChild("Backpack")
        local cl = CoolSword:Clone()
        cl.Name = "Tool"
        cl.Parent = plr.Backpack
        -- save
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(BuySword)

script.Parent.Mousewaterswordbutton:Connect(function()
    BuySword(game.Players.LocalPlayer)
end)
```

please can you show me what is wrong with my code so I can fix it thank you.

Comment: Define not working, e.g. is the callback even called? What is `Mousewaterswordbutton`? This code appears to work fine, if you intended to give the sword when the player spawns.

Comment: Is this a Script or a LocalScript?